# how to get selected option from a dropdownlist using jquery?

Tags: jquery

My dropdownlist has an ID of ID=ddltest

How can I reference the selected item in the drop down using jquery?

Comment: If your question has been answered to your liking, please mark an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#ddltest").val();
```

will give you the value of the selected item

If you want the actual selected item itself:

```
$("#ddltest option:selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#ddltest").val();
```

Comment: its funny I have never used the jQuery keyword, always use the $.

Comment: Using the `jQuery` name is certainly more portable than assuming `$` will be an alias to `jQuery`.  I wonder what percentage of sites use multiple JS frameworks that want to use the `$` alias...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#ddltest option:selected').each(function(){
 alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: If you're selecting by ID, you don't need to specify the tag. There should only be one element with that ID. e.g. $('#ddtest option:selected')